# HKStatisticsQuery Not Working for querying body temperature

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm creating an app which the user can add an instance of temperature (Writing to HKHealthStore), and where I want to query using HKStatisticsQuery, finding the discrete max and min for the interval of time, however it's not printing anything. I tried HKStatisticsQuery for other things like BMI, but nothing outputs on the simulator.

```
    
    var healthStore: HKHealthStore?
    
    init() {
        if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            healthStore = HKHealthStore()
        }
    }
    
    func writeTemp(startDate: Date, tempToAdd: Double) {
        let tempType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyTemperature)!
        
        let endDate = startDate + 60 * 60 // add 1h to startDate
        let stepsSample = HKQuantitySample(type: tempType, quantity: HKQuantity.init(unit: HKUnit.degreeFahrenheit(), doubleValue: tempToAdd), start: startDate, end: endDate)
        
        // After creating the sample, we call healthStore.save()
        
        if let healthStore = healthStore {
            healthStore.save(stepsSample, withCompletion: { (success, error) -> Void in
                
                if error != nil {
                    // something happened
                    print("error = \(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }
                
                if success {
                    print("Steps successfully saved in HealthKit")
                    return
                } else {
                    // something happened again
                    print("Unhandled case!")
                }
                
            })
        }
        
    }
    
    func calculateTemp(completion: @escaping (HKStatisticsQuery?) -> Void){
        let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
        var query: HKStatisticsQuery?
        var query2: HKStatisticsQuery?
        let tempType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyTemperature)!
        let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -3, to: Date())
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)
        
        var minima: Double?
        var maxima: Double?
        
        
        query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: tempType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .discreteMax){ (query, results, error) in
//            minima = results?.minimumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.degreeFahrenheit())
//            print(minima!)
            print(error!)
            print("HI")
        }
        
        query2 = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: tempType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .discreteMin){(query, results, error) in
//            maxima = results?.maximumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.degreeFahrenheit())
//            print(maxima!)
            print(error!)
            print("HI")
        }
        
        healthStore.execute(query!)
        healthStore.execute(query2!)
        
    }
    
    func requestAuthorization(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        
        let tempType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyTemperature)!
        
        guard let healthStore = self.healthStore else { return completion(false) }
        
        healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: [tempType], read: [tempType]) { (success, error) in
            completion(success)
        }
        
    }
    func testStatisticsQueryDiscrete() {
            guard let bodyMassType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass) else {
                fatalError("*** Unable to get the body mass type ***")
            }

            let query = HKStatisticsQuery.init(quantityType: bodyMassType,
                                               quantitySamplePredicate: nil,
                                               options: [HKStatisticsOptions.discreteMax, HKStatisticsOptions.separateBySource]) { (query, results, error) in
                print("Total: \(String(describing: results?.maximumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.pound())))")
                for source in (results?.sources)! {
                    print("Seperate Source: \(results?.maximumQuantity(for: source)?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.pound()))")
                }
            }

        healthStore?.execute(query)
    }
    func test(){
        guard let bodyMassType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass) else {
            fatalError("*** Unable to get the body mass type ***")
        }
        print(bodyMassType)
        let query = HKStatisticsQuery.init(quantityType: bodyMassType,
                                           quantitySamplePredicate: nil,
                                           options: [HKStatisticsOptions.discreteMax, HKStatisticsOptions.separateBySource]) { (query, results, error) in
            print("Total: \(String(describing: results?.maximumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.pound())))")
            self.healthStore?.execute(query)
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Could someone please give any possible nudges on what's going on?

Comment: Your code is basically correct. But I don't think that there is any sample data on the simulator. I ran it on my phone and it returns correct values. I tested with discreteAverage instead of discreateMax.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I made the option writeTemp() for that reason, and if I check in the  Health app, then the data gets added. So, that's quite weird.